# asp.net project publish on iis error on brow page

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008

i publish my **ASP.NET** project as. *Build / publish*. choice of publish is file system and directory is

> IIS/wwwroot

Using asp.net and iis7.

When I want browse page from browser it show error with web-config file. You can see it on my page

> http://isprojekty.fri.uniza.sk/MainForm.aspx

Can you help me where is problem ?

thx.

Comment: this is not the actual error. You need ether to look at your web server on EventViwer the real error, ether follow the instruction of the page to see the real error on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can remotely access the server where it is deployed, you could try accessing your site from there, and then you can see the error, if you have customErrors="remoteOnly". Otherwise, you will need to update your web.config to allow you to see the error message (but put it back again right away, because everyone else will be able to see it also).

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

is what you need to change it to.